# Help with Telescopic Series with 3 terms in denominator

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

[image]

All the examples i have done and seen only have 2 terms in the denominator so I am a bit stuck with this one. I have attached what I have done so far, not sure how to proceed with it.

Thank you for the hints they were useful, after working it out more I ended up with the following but now i am confused on what to do next, do I have to do another partial fraction decomposition?
[My work after the hints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xcrq.jpg)

Comment: Note that our expression is equal to $\frac{1/2}{n(n+1)}-\frac{1/2}{(n+1)(n+2)}$.

Comment: About the added work: The limit of $\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1/2}{(n+1)(n+2)}$ is $1/4$.

Comment: so the limit of the second fraction equals to 0?  from what I know it would be .5/ (infinity*infinity) right? Also thanks for all your help! summer calculus class is very fast which makes it difficult!

Comment: I don't like to treat "$\infty$" as a number. Imagine that $n$ grows without bound. Then $\frac{1/2}{(n+1)(n+2)}$ approaches $0$.  Much more informally, perhaps too informally, **all** the terms except the first get cancelled out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close to the end. Express what you got as
$$\left(\frac{1/2}{n}-\frac{1/2}{n+1}\right)-\left(\frac{1/2}{n+1}-\frac{1/2}{n+2}\right).$$
It looks a little better as
$$\frac{1/2}{n(n+1)}-\frac{1/2}{(n+1)(n+2)}.$$
Now add up, and (in either version) watch almost all the terms cancel.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n(n+1)(n+2)}
&=\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left[\frac1{n(n+1)}-\frac1{(n+1)(n+2)}\right]\\
&=\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n(n+1)}-\frac12\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{n(n+1)}\\
\end{align}
$$
**More Generally**
$$
\begin{align}
&\frac1{n(n+1)\dots(n+k-1)}-\frac1{(n+1)(n+2)\dots(n+k)}\\
&=\frac1{(n+1)(n+2)\dots(n+k-1)}\left(\frac1n-\frac1{n+k}\right)\\
&=\frac{k}{n(n+1)\dots(n+k)}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\frac1{n(n+1)\dots(n+k)}=\frac1k\left[\frac1{n(n+1)\dots(n+k-1)}-\frac1{(n+1)(n+2)\dots(n+k)}\right]
$$